# changing a URL for an image that is inside a DIV that has an ID

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a page that has a lot of linked images. I would like to change just one of the image links (it's the logo) using javascript. I can not directly edit the "body" html, but I can put js in the "head" region. The image and link is inside a DIV that has an ID (as below)

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="ctl00">
  <h1 class="logo">
  <a href="http://www.store.domain.co.nz" title="Menswear"><img src="/user/files/logo.png title="Menswear" alt="Menswear"></a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

and I want to change the html to:

```
<div id="ctl00">
    <h1 class="logo">
<a href="http://www.domain.co.nz" title="Menswear"><img src="/user/files/logo.png title="Menswear" alt="Menswear"></a>
</h1>
</div>
```

Basically I want to remove the ".store" from the URL, but only this instance, not all URLs on the page.

Comment: If you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `getElementById` to get the `div` container
2. Use `getElementsByTagName('a')[0]` to get the first anchor
3. Use `replace()` to strip out `store.`

```js
var href = document.getElementById('ctl00').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;

document.getElementById('ctl00').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = href.replace('store.', '');
```

```html
<div id="ctl00">
  <h1 class="logo">
<a href="http://www.store.domain.co.nz" title="Menswear"><img src="/user/files/logo.png" title="Menswear" alt="Menswear"/></a>
</h1>
</div>
```